# Allow only work time in reservations table

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, schedule, postgresql-9.2

PostgreSql 9.2 Reservation table is defined as

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;
CREATE TABLE schedule (
  id serial primary key,
  during tsrange not null,
  EXCLUDE USING gist (during WITH &&)
);
```

Holidays are listed in table

```
CREATE TABLE holiday ( day primary key );
```

Work hours are from 8 to 18:00  in work days and reservatons can be done by 30 minute intervals only.
How to add constraints to during values so that it allows only reservations during work time:

1. Start and end dates in tsrange are always same.
2. Start and end dates cannot be saturday and sunday
3. Start and end dates cannot appear in public holiday table
4. Start time can be only 8:00 , 8:30, 9:00, 9:30, ... 16:00, 16:30, 17:00 or 17:30 inclusive
5. End time can be only 8:30, 9:00, 9:30, ... 16:00, 16:30, 17:00, 17:30 or 18:00 exclusive

Is it reasonable to add those or some of those constraints to this table ?
If yes, how to add ?
schedule table structure can changed if this helps.

Comment: Some of those can be done with simple `CHECK` constraints. I'm not sure you can implement a negative foreign key constraint directly for the public holidays; consider using a trigger for this.

Comment: I'm new to tsrange type. Can you provide some example, especially fot time constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change you table definition and add some `check` constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE schedule (
  id serial primary key,
  during tsrange not null check(
    (lower(during)::date = upper(during)::date) and 
    (date_trunc('hour', upper(during)) + INTERVAL '30 min' * ROUND(date_part('minute', upper(during)) / 30.0) = upper(during)) and
    (date_trunc('hour', lower(during)) + INTERVAL '30 min' * ROUND(date_part('minute', lower(during)) / 30.0) = lower(during)) and
    (lower(during)::time >= '8:00'::time and upper(during)::time <= '18:00'::time) and
    (date_part('dow', lower(during)) in (1,2,3,4,5) and date_part('dow', upper(during)) in (1,2,3,4,5))
  ),
  EXCLUDE USING gist (during WITH &&)
);
```

The checks are in this order

- start and end day are the same
- start / end can must be on 30 min boundary
- and between 8:00 .. 18:00
- only weekdays

We need something in `holiday` table:
    insert into holiday values ('2012-11-28');

`check` can not reference other table hence we need trigger function (it might be better to put all check into this function i.e. have them at one place):

```
create function holiday_check() returns trigger language plpgsql stable as $$
begin
    if exists (select * from holiday where day in (lower(NEW.during)::date, upper(NEW.during)::date)) then
        raise exception 'public holiday';
    else
        return NEW;
    end if;
end;
$$;
```

Then we need to create triggers before `insert`/`update`:

```
create trigger holiday_check_i before insert on schedule for each row execute procedure holiday_check();
create trigger holiday_check_u before update on schedule for each row execute procedure holiday_check();
```

Finally, some tests:

```
-- OK
insert into schedule(during) values (tsrange('2012-11-26 08:00', '2012-11-26 09:00'));
INSERT 0 1

-- out of business hours
insert into schedule(during) values (tsrange('2012-11-26 04:00', '2012-11-26 05:00'));
ERROR:  new row for relation "schedule" violates check constraint "schedule_during_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (12, ["2012-11-26 04:00:00","2012-11-26 05:00:00")).

-- End time can be only 8:30, 9:00, 9:30, ... 16:00, 16:30, 17:00, 17:30 or 18:00 exclusive
insert into schedule(during) values (tsrange('2012-11-26 08:00', '2012-11-26 09:10'));
ERROR:  new row for relation "schedule" violates check constraint "schedule_during_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (13, ["2012-11-26 08:00:00","2012-11-26 09:10:00")).

-- Start time can be only 8:00 , 8:30, 9:00, 9:30, ... 16:00, 16:30, 17:00 or 17:30 inclusive
insert into schedule(during) values (tsrange('2012-11-26 11:24', '2012-11-26 13:00'));
ERROR:  new row for relation "schedule" violates check constraint "schedule_during_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (14, ["2012-11-26 11:24:00","2012-11-26 13:00:00")).

-- holiday
insert into schedule(during) values (tsrange('2012-11-28 10:00', '2012-11-28 13:00'));
ERROR:  public holiday
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Excellent. Btw. Have you looked the updated question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433863/how-to-return-only-work-time-from-reservations-in-postgresql . It looks like your to this question answer returns wrong data since constructed select returns overlapping ranges.

Comment: Why do you create two triggers? This could be done with a single `create trigger holiday_check_i before insert or update ... ` statement? Is there any benefit on having two?

Answer (score 5):

You can solve everything except item 3. with plain [**`CHECK`** constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS):

Use dedicated [**range functions** `lower(anysrange)` and `upper(anyrange)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html#RANGE-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) to access lower / upper bounds of the range.

> 1.) Start and end dates in tsrange are always same.

```
CONSTRAINT schedule_same_day
CHECK (lower(during)::date = upper(during)::date)
```

> 2.) Start and end dates cannot be saturday and sunday

Use [`isodow`, not `dow`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) for a simpler expression.

```
CONSTRAINT schedule_no weekend
CHECK (EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM lower(during)) < 6)  -- upper is on same day
```

> **3.) Start and end dates cannot appear in public holiday table**

For this you'd need a **trigger** like:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_during_no_holy()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   IF EXISTS (SELECT FROM holiday WHERE day = lower(NEW.during)) THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Day too holy: %', lower(NEW.during);
   END IF;

   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$;

CREATE TRIGGER insupbef_holycheck
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON schedule
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_during_no_holy();
```

> 4.) Start time can be only 8:00, 8:30, 9:00, 9:30, ..., 16:00, 16:30, 17:00, or 17:30 inclusive.
> 5.) End time can be only 8:30, 9:00, 9:30, ..., 16:00, 16:30, 17:00, 17:30, or 18:00 exclusive.

```sql
CONSTRAINT schedule_8_inc_to_18_exc_half_hours CHECK (
        lower(during)::time BETWEEN time '8:00'AND time '17:30' -- time range
    AND upper(during)::time BETWEEN time '8:30'AND time '18:00'
    AND EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM lower(during)) IN (0, 30) -- only :00 or :30
    AND EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM upper(during)) IN (0, 30)
    AND lower_inc(during)          -- lower bound always incl.
    AND upper_inc(during) = false  -- upper bound always excl.
   )
```

Update: in **Postgres 14** or newer use `date_bin()`:

```sql
CONSTRAINT schedule_8_inc_to_18_exc_half_hours CHECK (
       lower(during) < upper(during)
   AND lower(during)::time >= time '08:00'
   AND upper(during)::time <= time '18:00'
   AND during = date_bin('30 min', during, '2000-01-01')  -- only :00 or :30 exactly
   AND lower_inc(during)          -- lower bound always incl.
   AND upper_inc(during) = false  -- upper bound always excl.
   )
```

This also enforces your additional requirement to "*to restrict seconds and fractional seconds"*.

See:

- [What is the fastest way to truncate timestamps to 5 minutes in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299342/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-truncate-timestamps-to-5-minutes-in-postgres/75160734#75160734)

Comment: Thank you. Excellent. It looks like 4.) allows also non-half hour times like 8:15, 8:0:01 etc. How to add constraint so that only half-hour times are allowed ?

Comment: @Andrus: I added that and also the check for inclusive / exclusive border. You could split items up into individual `CHECK` constraints with obvious names for error messages ...

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter The first constraint. It doesn't make sense. Maybe he wanted equal dates, not date/time.